# garmin GPSMAP 76CSx gps usb connection

Tags: usb, gps

Now that I've discovered this useful place for solving problems I'd like to find the solution to my next issue.
I used to be able to connect my Garmin GPSMAP 76CSx by usb to my old PC with Ubuntu, it was a complicated solution (for me) but sadly I can't find it again for this PC. Can anyone direct me to a fix. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which works with my device: http://javier-rutas.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/gps-plugin-garmin-en-linux-ubuntu.html

Basically, you have to add the following repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andreas-diesner/garminplugin 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install garminplugin
```

In the next step, you have to go to firefox and click in Preferences, Tools,  Defaul user agent --- GarminPluginFake -- Firefox

I hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked, I also found a lot of useful information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GarminGPSMap76CSx